# Having trouble figuring out how to generate URL that points to an image for the src of my <img> element on successful AJAX request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

So the AJAX request below inserts a comment in the database and then displays it on the page by appending some HTML that contains stuff like `<a>` element that sends the user to the profile page of the author of the commend, and an `<img>` element that displays the profile picture of the user who posted the comment.

My problem is that I can't figure out how to generate the URLs used in the  element href property and the  element src property. As you can see, they're still empty as I'm trying to figure out how to populate them

Usually, if I were doing this using PHP, i'd do this:

```
<img class='comment-picture' src='{{ url("storage/uploads/profile_pictures/edited/".$comment->user->image_file_name )}}'>
<a href='{{ route('profile', $comment->user->username) }}'>
```

I might be able to hardcode the URLs but that is definitely not my goal. Any tips, pointers or documents which might be related to my problem?

PHP

```
class CommentsController extends Controller
{
    public function postComment(Request $request){
        $userId = $request['userId'];
        $imageId = $request['imageId'];
        $commentText = $request['comment'];
        $image = Image::find($imageId);

        $comment = new Comment();
        $comment->user_id = $userId;
        $comment->image_id = $imageId;
        $comment->comment = $commentText;
        $comment->save();

        $image->updateComments();

        return response()->json(['comment'=>$comment, 'image'=>$image]);
    }
}
```

JavaScript

```
$('.post-comment').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var userId = $("input[name=user_id]").val();
    var imageId = $("input[name=image_id]").val();
    var comment = $("textarea[name=comment]").val();

    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: urlComment,
        data: {
            userId: userId,
            imageId: imageId,
            comment: comment,
            _token: token
        }
    }).done(function(response) {
        var commentsCount = response.image.comments;
        var comment = response.comment.comment;

        var appendHtml =    '<div class="comment-flexbox">' +
                                '<div class="comment-container">' +
                                    '<a href="#">' +
                                        '<img class="comment-picture" src="">' +
                                    '</a>' +
                                '</div>' +
                                '<div class="comment-info-container"' +
                                    '<a href="#">' +
                                    '<p>' + comment + '</p>' +
                                '</div>' +
                            '</div>';

                            console.log(response);

        $("textarea[name=comment]").val("");
        $('.comments-container').append(appendHtml);
        $('.comments-count').html("<i class='far fa-comments fa-fw'></i>" + commentsCount + " Comments")
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The src="" in your image tag is empty. Wouldn't you just do...

```
'<img class="comment-picture" src="'+response.image'+">'
```

???

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
<img class='comment-picture' src="{{ url('storage/uploads/profile_pictures/edited/')}}{{$comment->user->image_file_name}}">
```